# Does my code for Heap sort run in O(n lgn) time? Just want to confirm

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, heapsort

What is the complexity of this code? I think it is O(n lgn), but I am relatively new to time complexity so I just want to make sure. Im pretty sure you can also use a maxHeap to get the same results, but I found the use of minHeap to be more intuitive.(I just edited this)

```python
def minHeap(array, n, i): #creates minHeap of array and returns it
smallest = i

left = 2*i+1
right = 2*i+2

if left < n:
    if array[smallest] > array[left]:
        smallest = left
if right < n:
    if array[smallest] > array[right]:
        smallest = right



if smallest <> i:
    array[smallest] , array[i] = array[i], array[smallest]
    minHeap(array, n, left)
    minHeap(array, n, right)
    minHeap(array, n, i)
    return array
else:
    if left < n:
        minHeap(array, n, left)
    if right < n:
        minHeap(array, n, right)
    if left < n:
        if array[smallest] > array[left]:
            smallest = left
    if right < n:
        if array[smallest] > array[right]:
            smallest = right
    if smallest <> i:
        array[smallest] , array[i] = array[i], array[smallest]
    return array

def heapSort(arr): #the actual sorting algorithm that uses a minHeap
    minheap = minHeap(arr, len(arr), 0)
    sortedarray = []

    for n in range(0,len(arr)):
        sortedarray.append(minheap[0])
        minheap[0], minheap[-1] = minheap[-1], minheap[0]
        minheap.pop(-1)
        minheap = minHeap(minheap, len(minheap), 0)
    return sortedarray
```

Comment: What is `minHeap()` supposed to do? Because `minHeap([2, 3, 4, 1], 4, 0)` doesn't build a heap and that seems valid input.

Comment: dhke- I just edited my minHeap() code, so it should work now

Comment: [No, it's still not making a min heap.](https://ideone.com/qQtcwf) This doesn't really look like a min heap data structure at all - there's no heap-push or heap-pop operation. It looks like the only thing `minHeap` gets right is putting the minimum element in front, which happens to be the only thing the not-actually-a-heapsort `heapSort` relies on.

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(N²)` with `N` the length of `arr`.

You are calling `N` times the function `minHeap`:

```
for n in range(0,len(arr)):
    ...
    minheap = minHeap(minheap, len(minheap), 0)
```

And that function `minHeap` calls itself recursively for all the possible values of `i`. Apart from that recursive call, the code of `minHeap` seems to execute in `O(1)`. The complexity of `minHeap` is `O(N)`.

A simple trick allows you to compute the complexity: count the number of times `minHeap` is called. With just a `print(i)` at the begin of that function, you'll see that the time complexity of `minHeap` is linear to the size of its initial input.

You're calling `N` times a function that is `O(N)`, giving you a total complexity of `O(N²)`.

Comment: How can I reduce the complexity of the code to O(n lgn)? Again, I am new to heaps and really don't seem to understand it too much.

Comment: @SiddharthG, read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap it is all explained there. Also, I doubt that your heap creation is O(n), but I didn't examine that deeply.